# How to make menu appear below dropdownmenubutton in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I have set menuMaxHeight as it was taking up a lot of screen.
My menu appears above the menubutton.

Here is the widget

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        menuMaxHeight: 300,
        //isDense: true,
        hint: Text("State",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF8B8B8B),fontSize: 15),),
        //alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        value: stateValue,
       // elevation: 2,
       //underline: null,
       isExpanded: true,
       style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            stateValue = newValue!;
          });
        },
        items: <String>['AL' ,'AK' ,'AZ' ,'AR' ,'CA' ,'CZ' ,'CO' ,'CT' ,'DE' ,'DC' ,'FL' ,'GA' ,'GU' ,'HI' ,'ID' ,'IL' ,'IN' ,'IA' ,'KS' ,'KY' ,'LA' ,'ME' ,'MD' ,'MA' ,'MI' ,'MN' ,'MS' ,'MO' ,'MT' ,'NE' ,'NV' ,'NH' ,'NJ' ,'NM' ,'NY' ,'NC' ,'ND' ,'OH' ,'OK' ,'OR' ,'PA' ,'PR' ,'RI' ,'SC' ,'SD' ,'TN' ,'TX' ,'UT' ,'VT' ,'VI' ,'VA' ,'WA' ,'WV' ,'WI' ,'WY' ,'null']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Is there a way to make menu appear below the button. I have seen documentation but have not been able to find a way for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2). It's based on Flutter's core DropdownButton with steady dropdown menu below the button and many other options you can customize to your needs.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.